# Firebase Remote Config

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Firebase is currently causing crashes at startup for my apps.

Specs: Unity 5.3.5f

I even tried using google's own test app here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity

Then imported firebase, configured everything on Firebase console, and built it in Android.

After the Unity logo disappears, the app just crashes.

I know how to logcat, but what useful messages should I look for?
Could this be the problem?

```
11-23 12:15:51.090 18781-18797/? E/firebase: local_class
11-23 12:15:51.160 18781-18797/? E/Unity: local_class
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Firebase.FirebaseHandler:LogMessage(LogLevel, String)
Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE:FirebaseApp_CreateInternal__SWIG_0()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateInternal()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:<Create>m__1()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateAndTrack(CreateDelegate)
Firebase.FirebaseApp:Create()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:get_DefaultInstance()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CheckDependencies()
UIHandler:Start() (at C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Compressed\quickstart-unity-master\remote_config\testapp\Assets\TestApp\UIHandler.cs:38)

(Filename: C Line: 0)
11-23 12:15:51.160 18781-18797/? E/firebase: Class com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp not found
11-23 12:15:51.162 18781-18797/? E/firebase: global_class
```

Answer (score 0):

I had another version of Google Play resolver from another package, so the first thing I did was to remove the older one.

Then from the menu choose Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve Client Jars.

That should automatically pull in the required dependencies and fix your issue.